# Android Studio - Using Service to call final() vs. FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, service

I have been scouting around for a while, but cannot locate any information for calling final() using started services... or rather, when not using bound services. There is tons of info for bound services, but I already have two pretty large "started services" without binding, so I didn't want to modify the existing services more than absolutely necessary.

My app works by reading bluetooth data every 10 seconds, and depending on the data read, the Service will change to a new activity. However, I cannot call final() from my services, so I fear that I might be endlessly stacking activities while the application/services are running.

To change activities, I had to add **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK**. Considering the below image/definition from the developer's page, this flag looks like it might already handle my stacking issue? I do NOT allow for users to use the back button on their phones as everything is handled via confirm/cancel buttons and the services. My app MUST be this way for a few reasons. Thus, keeping the stack order isn't important to my application.

[image]

Key Points -

- I want to ensure i'm not stacking up activities endlessly when starting new activities
- Flagging "new task" when starting activities via my services
- Stack order is not important to my app

Below is a very small cut of my code with comments to explain what i'm trying to do. Please make sure to look to the onDestroy() method of this service.

```
public class AlertService extends Service {

    final class Threader implements Runnable{
        // Scans bluetooth advertisement packets every 10 seconds
        // Thread Runs until interrupted
        // Stops service via service ID
        stopSelf(this.serviceID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
    }

    // Runs a thread until alert is found. 
    //    Alert calls thread.interrupt()
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startID){
        enableBluetooth();

        // Start Thread
        thread = new Thread(new Threader(startID));
        thread.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        thread.interrupt();
        Intent alertActivity = new Intent(this, AlertActivity.class)
        alertActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(alertActivity);
    }

   // Unused Method - We will not be binding
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** via recommendation to use android:taskAffinity - 
Using android:taskAffinity won't help me in this situation. By default, all activities in an application have the same affinity. When I create a new task by setting Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in the intent flags, the new activity will STILL be started in the same task if the activity has the same taskAffinity of the root activity in the task. Since I am just using the default affinity, everything should have the normal stack flow. I just cannot call finish(), which means that I am stacking up tons of activities.

Comment: Do you always want to have only one AlertActivity on a back stack?

Comment: @Sunhee The application starts with a "Home Service" running. When an alert is found, the Home Service is stopped and new activity is created along with starting the "Alert Service." However, many activities may be created during the Alert Service. Typically, an alert screen issues an alert, but a new activity will be created to give periodic updates. Later, an "all clear" message goes through, ending the alert service and restarting home service and home activity.

Comment: If you want to start only one AlertActivity, you have to set android:taskAffinity and android:excludeFromRecents to AlertActivity on Manifest.xml. **But**, please show me your sources, the activity source created after the Home Service stops and AlertActivity source?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want the source of the next activity to be started after the home service stops, and the alert service source? Can I PM these to you somehow, this is work related.

Comment: Yes, I want to check the activity source after the home service and AlertActivity source. What does it mean by PM?

Comment: Private message

Comment: May I just ask what it is you are looking for? Maybe I can post just that portion

Comment: @Sunee, What about using "android:noHistory"? A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it. This should work right? This won't add the activity to the stack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149866/discussion-between-sunhee-and-foxdonut).

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, each new activity called via Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, was creating a new instance of each activity and putting it on the stack. This is true. However, each activity is NOT making a new Task, which was one of my fears as well.

When I create a new task by setting Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK in the intent flags, the new activity will STILL be started in the same task (not in a new task) if the new activity has the same taskAffinity of the root activity in the task. Since I am just using the default affinity, every activity I create is being put into the same task. This means that nothing is acting any differently than the normal flow of creating activities and such.

Though, since I have disable the back button for my application, these activities created by flagging a new task are not finished, destroyed, or removed from the stack. To solve this, I will use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, which finds a running instance of an activity in the stack (if there is one) and closes all of the activities above it.

Since my application always starts with the home screen, then ends with the home screen, flagging "clear top" will always close all activities above my home screen. So, upon return to the home screen, the only item on the stack will be the home screen.

I will have to test this, but it seems that I will not call finish() from my home activity to achieve this result - Otherwise, upon returning to the home activity, not all of the stack will be cleared.

[image]